# Question about an example of non-integrable constraints

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, constrained-dynamics

The example is a thin disk rotating of an inclined plane. The disk can roll not only down the plane, but also "sideways". Let $(x,y)$ be the position of the CM, where the $y$ axis is down the slope and the $x$ axis is horizontal on the plane, the angle the disk has rolled w.r.t its symmetry axis be $\phi$, and the angle of the disk plane made with the $y$ axis be $\theta$. Then the constraints are
$$\dot{x}=R\dot{\phi}\sin\theta,\quad  \dot{y}=R\dot{\phi}\cos\theta$$
or
$$dx=R\sin\theta d\phi,\quad  dy=R\cos\theta d\phi$$
Then the author argued that the constraints are non-integrable as follows:

Suppose there were a constraint of the form
$$f(x,y,\phi,\theta,t)=0$$
then
$$0=df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy+\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}d\phi+\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}d\theta+\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}dt$$
Then $$dx=R\sin\theta d\phi, \quad dy=R\cos\theta d\phi$$ implies
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=1,\quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}=R\sin\theta, \quad\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0,\quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}=0.$$

...

I can't see how to get the last conclusion above.

Comment: $\uparrow$ Which author?

Comment: I am reading the lecture notes by Sunil Golwala from Caltech.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21170/2451

Comment: I understand the argument in the related post. But still don't understand that in my post.

Comment: look here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/482949/non-integrable-differential-equation-and-non-holonomic-contraints/719438#719438