# Differential equation for describing a moving disk

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, constrained-dynamics

I'm doing some self-study on physics and came across this problem:

> A disk rolls without slipping across a horizontal plane. The plane of the disk remains vertical, but it is free to rotate about a vertical axis. What generalized coordinates may be used to describe the motion? Write a differential equation describing the rolling constraint. Is this equation integrable? Justify your answer by a physical argument. Is the constraint holonomic?

This is a problem in the book Thornton/Marion's Classical Dynamics of Particles and Systems,
and there's a [Chegg solution](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/student-solutions-manual-for-thornton-marion-s-classical-dynamics-of-particles-and-systems-5th-edition-chapter-7-solutions-9780534408978) which goes:

[image]

My question is: How did they arrive at the differential equation $$ dx  cos(\phi) + dy  sin(\phi) = Rd\theta~? $$

Comment: Look here https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/482949/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

the disk can rotate about the z-axis with the angle $~\varphi~$ and about the y-axis with the angle $~\theta~$, thus the rotation matrix is:

$$\mathbf R=\mathbf R_z(\varphi)\,\mathbf R_y(\theta)$$

from here you obtain the angular velocity  in inertial system

$$\vec\omega= \left[ \begin {array}{c} -\sin \left( \varphi  \right) \dot\theta 
\\  \cos \left( \varphi  \right) \dot\theta 
\\  \dot\varphi \end {array} \right]
$$

the disk  can move in the x-y plane with the velocities  $~\dot x~,\dot y$

$$\vec v_d=\left[ \begin {array}{c} {\dot x}\\ {\dot y}
\\ 0\end {array} \right]
$$

the velocity at  contact point  with the plane is zero (roll condition) . you obtain
$$\vec v_c=\vec v_d-\vec \omega\times\, \begin{bmatrix}
   0 \\
   0 \\
   -R \\
 \end{bmatrix}=\vec 0\quad\Rightarrow$$

$${\dot x}=-\cos \left( \varphi  \right) \dot\theta \,R\tag 1$$
$$  {\dot y}=-\sin \left( \varphi  \right) \dot\theta  \,R$$ $\quad\Rightarrow$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\tan(\varphi)$$

equations (1) and (2) are the nonholonomic constraint  equations